# In which Tier is Catalina RealmBase situated?

Tags: java, tomcat, server, catalina, multi-tier

I am confused if Catalina RealmBase (DataSourceRealm, or the others) situated in Presentation Tier or in the business Logic Tier (Integration or Business Tier).

I created a `class SignatureRealm extends DataSourceRealm` to authenticate the users.

The Problem is that now I am confused in which Tier is my class `SignatureRealm` located.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Authentication and authorization are typically not thought of as being "in a tier". If you absolutely had to fit them into one, it would be the business logic, since it is tied to what users should be able to do (which is itself a business requirement). It's certainly *not* in the presentation tier.